# pass variable value by clicking mouse to the servlet in java

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, javabeans, session-variables

I have one java server page in which values are returning from database and using bean concept 
and on jsp page i have used c:for each loop so i am able to get the answer so i have made one particular column as link using like this

```
<td><a href = retrieve_image>${item.getIid()}</a></td>
```

this code is working  what i want when i click mouse on this id then this id value should pass into that  servlet retrieve_image, so i can perform my task so anyone please tell me is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Simple you could pass the value inside your `<a>` like this as query string,

```
<td><a href = "retrieve_image?Id=${item.getIid()}">${item.getIid()}</a></td>
```

Get the value from the `Id` in your servlet . you will get the value for current iteration inside the `for-each` loop as you print `${item.getIid()}`

Hope this helps !!

Comment: welcome :) happy to help . Feel free to up vote and accept the answer if it helped . so that it would useful to ohters

Comment: sir my reputation is not enough to vote the answer... :( i want to vote this answer...

Comment: If it has solved your problem . Accept the answer by clicking the 'Tick' mark that appears to the left of my answer